# MySQL CLI: unknown option: enable-cleartext-plugin

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

This question has been asked a couple of times out here, but I'm not able to enable cleartext plugin. I'm using mySQL CLI to access an RDS(Engine version: `5.7.26`) instance using the command

`mysql -h $RDSHOST -u <Username> --password=$TOKEN --enable-cleartext-plugin --port=3306 --ssl-ca=<path to pem file>`

I get the following error:

`mysql: unknown option '--enable-cleartext-plugin'`

I installed mySQL by running `yum install curl mysql -y`. But in the logs I see `maria-db` being installed, is there something wrong out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: do not use the mariadb client to connect to an AWS RDS instance using IAM Authentication.

Here's a quick answer for your issue, and another for the one you'll hit after removing the flag:

You are definitely running a mariadb client, you can confirm it with `mysql --version`.

On the paper mariadb always enable plugins, thus does not provide the `enable-cleartext-plugin` flag on the client.
However —after losing several hours yesterday on the same issue— it appears that the client does not even use the cleartext plugin when you try to authenticate against a AWS RDS instance with IAM Authentication (*tested with mariadb 10.3 and 10.5 clients against a MySQL 8.0.23 server*).

In the end you must use the 'official' mysql client for this usecase. Some linux distributions provide this client through another package like Percona-Server (*which is the case for Arch Linux and Exherbo at least*).

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you're using a MariaDB client, the --enable-cleartext-plugin option isn't required.

According to the article found here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/

Comment: What about mysql?

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to re execute this then I could login with the special user:

ALTER USER 'myuser' IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS';